# Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime with LINQ Where?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, .net-3.5, linq-to-entities

I have the statement:

```
var persons = _context.Persons.AsExpandable()
                                   .Where(predicate).ToList();
```

When I run the above, it gives me the error `Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime`.

If I format it with `ToString("g")`, I don't get the error, but the problem is I have a lot of columns returning and I want to return all of them and don't and don't want to have to explicitly list every column in a `Select`.

If I want to only return 99 out of 100 rows in a SELECT, would I have do it explicitly?

Comment: What kind of LINQ is this? What is `_context`?

Comment: @SLaks - LINQ to Entities.

Comment: @SLaks - The .Net connector if that is what you mean.

Comment: I see; I had forgotten that they added EF support.

Comment: @SLaks I believe _context is the db context, Persons is a table. What I don't understand is what `AsExpandable` does and also, could you edit with the value of predicate?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal - Entity Framework's query processing pipeline cannot handle invocation expressions, which is why you need to call AsExpandable on the first object in the query. By calling AsExpandable, you activate LINQKit's expression visitor class which substitutes invocation expressions with simpler constructs that Entity Framework can understand. LINQKit.dll is the reference.

Answer (score 3):

`Adding Convert Zero Datetime=true;` to my connection string solved the problem.  The particular record I was trying to retrieve had a datetime value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`